# Aquamacs: why does M-p suddenly start entering pi?

Tags: emacs, erlang, aquamacs

Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS appkit-1344.72 Version 10.10.2 (Build 14C109))
 of 2016-09-19 on 24a02dbf6b34ae061ef4df89f15bfbc5d3ed497e

OSX 10.10.5

Typically, when I'm in an erlang shell I can use `M-p` to cycle through previous commands, but occasionally when I do that the pi symbol gets entered, and I can't get the emacs functionality back.  After that, `M-p` enters pi no matter what type of buffer I am in. I thought I had a fix: quit Aquamacs, but now that doesn't work anymore.

And, why is there no autocompletion of function names in the erlang shell--like with an erlang shell running in a Terminal window?

emacs is soooo frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at Oliver Müller's [blog](http://blog.oliver-mueller.com/-234). Somehow, in the course of (mis)typing emacs key sequences, I ended up with this (see the Aquamacs menu bar) :

```
Options > 
     Option, Command, Meta keys >
          ✓Option for composed characters
           Option is Meta
```

Simply clicking `Option is Meta` returns Aquamacs to its default state, allowing me to use the Option key as the Meta key again for emacs key sequences.

Note: in short order some key sequence I typed changed the Option key back to `Option for composed characters`.

Edit: It looks like `C-;` might be the offending key sequence.  In any case, `C-;` can be used to toggle *Option is Meta* on and off.

Comment: Thanks this is great as it is so frustrating when this happens